# Importing dynamic datasets within a {golem} package

Tags: r, shiny, golem

I currently have a data_prep.R file that I use to pull in data using SQL queries and then wrangle the data into suitable data frames for use within my {golem} package. At the end of this script I have

`usethis::usedata(df, overwrite = T)`

From research it seems that this file should go into the /data-raw folder as you are not supposed to execute code in the /R folder. When ran, it constructs my data frames and then places them within the /data folder. However, this script does not seem to get ran whenever I run the application, moreover, the data frames will remain unchanged until I manually run the data_prep.R script again.

My application relies on the new data coming in and as such I would need this data_prep.R file to run whenever the app is launched.

Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked this out by placing the data_prep.R script into the application base directory and sourcing the file within the app_server.R file.

```
source("./data_prep.R")
```

This runs the script on app start and pulls the data frames from the server allowing the data to be up to date.

Answer (score 0):

The call of `usethis::usedata(df, overwrite = T)` create you a dataset you can load when your package is in use.
You should load explicitly the dataset in your app using `data(df)` in the piece of code where the data is needed.

Comment: Hey thanks for you answer, loading the data doesn't seem to be the issue. It's refreshing the data when the app loads. The data_prep.R script calls in the updated tables and assigns them for use, I want this to run on app start. Where would you propose I put the `data(df)` call, within app_server.R?

Comment: yes put ``data(df)`` in your server module